# jQuery UI resize - DIV Rounded Corners With Border

Tags: jquery, user-interface, resize, rounded-corners

There are many jquery rounded corner plugins however I can't seem to find/or get to work the solution i'm looking for.

I have a DIV with a 1px solid border, some corner plugins remove the border, some don't. I need to find one that doesn't and that can also be toggled on/off.

The reason for the toggle is that none of the corner plugins I've found support jQuery UI resize (maybe obvious reasons because the plugins append layers etc.) so what I need is a plugin that can support borders, and do the following:

Step 1). Apply corner effect
Step 2). User clicks the resize handle so corners are removed (using function call on the resize start event).
Step 3). On resize stop (stop event function) re-apply the borders.

Can anyone help with a solution?

Regards

Comment: I have created similar for myself a week ago but didn't need to change the borders at all for resizing...They just work fine. Have look at it on hci.me.uk and on the top section click on the contact link. playwith it... if its something you like I can paste the code here

Comment: For standard resizing it works okay, its when they have rounded corners applied to them through some sort of plugin (not CSS). I couldn't see rounded corners in your example.

Comment: The contact form DIV has 5px radius corners. isn't that what you mean?

Comment: Not on my screen it doesn't, I'm using IE8.

Comment: Forget IE 7 and 8 for rounded corners. its just going to create trouble for you. support rounded corners only for ff/chrome/ie9/safari

Comment: I see, thanks for advice - maybe IE9 may change things? Haven't looked at it yet.

Answer (score 0):

I use DD_roundies with draggable elements. I can also change the attributes of the border and it updates. Works great in all browsers.

http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_roundies/